# Keep pitch (focus) on player

Tags: java, opengl, game-engine

There is a camera with position x, y, z, pitch and yaw variables. There is a player with x, y, z and rotationY variables.

I can change the pitch manually in-game with this code:

`float pitchChange = Mouse.getDY() * 0.2f;
pitch -= pitchChange;`

I also have a terrain in my game, the camera cannot get below a certain point (10f above the terrain), it keeps 'floating'.

In the image below. The arrow represents the camera pointing direction and the color matches the player. The red one is how it is suppose to be on a flat terrain. As you can see, when I move downwards on the terrain, the camera keeps pointing forward instead of pointing to a certain point on my player, until I come back up to the same height or adjust the pitch manually. How can this be fixed by pitching the camera? (See second image)

[image: How it is right now]

[image: How I want it]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a camera representation with `eye` and `focus point` would suit your needs better. If you're bound to the `pitch` representation, you can calculate the angle as follows:

```
viewDirection = normalize(playerPosition - cameraPosition);
camera.pitch = Math.asin(viewDirection.y);
// pitch = 0 for horizontal view directions
// pitch > 0 for upward view directions
```

Depending on your angle definition, you might need to multiply `pitch` by `-1`. Be aware that the resulting angle is specified in radians.